# Accidentally deleted all Mail - How can I get it back?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, time-machine, mail-rules

In Apple Mail, I accidentally marked all messages in the `Inbox` folder as Junk (I meant to mark as read) and it appears all mail was deleted permanently.
My `Mailbox Behaviours` specify

[image]

Yet the deleted mail is neither on the server, nor do I have a folder for deleted messages or so. I have an **inactive** rule which would delete messages marked as junk, but as I said, it is inactive. I might however have clicked `Apply Rules` on the inbox when everything was still there (I do not know whether inactive rules are applied in that case).

Is the mail permanently deleted and if yes, how do I restore it from my time machine backup? Is it sufficient to simply restore the `~/Library/Mail/V2` contents?

Comment: Check to see if you can still use "Undo Mark as Junk Mail" under the Edit Menu (or just ⌘Z).

Comment: Already did, I cannot.

Comment: In that case, yes, you may go ahead and restore the folder that contains your mail accounts (V2, I assume in your case). I have used this solution many a time due to being just a bit too clever in my manipulation of information. Just make sure that you capture a backup that is prior to the "junk mail incident", which from here forth we shall never mention again!

Comment: I find it strange though that all messages are deleted from the server as well, despite the option being unchecked.

Comment: Indeed. That being said, I wonder if it may have to do with the server not having "finished" the move from inbox to junk mail. Perhaps those emails are in a form of limbo until the entire file move can be completed. If it's been sufficient time since the"incident" (I thought we were never going to go there again), that's likely not the case. Just to be sure, are these emails on your server's 'Deleted' mail box per chance?

Comment: I checked and the mail is still on the server for the `POP` account, but not on the `IMAP` account, so it could be protocol-related.

Comment: One last Hail Mary pass, do you have any other devices that do have "delete messages on server" enabled? That may have been invoked after the move was made.